# Java regular expression for simple key-value pairs with a suffix

Tags: java, regex, key-value, keyvaluepair

Consider a set of strings like the following:

```
Memory size = 4,194,304 KB
Cache size=   32,768 K
Number of cores = 8
Note   =4,000,000 KB is less than 4 GB
```

Is there a generic and not too complex Java regular expression that matches each string entirely and produces the following groups?

```
"Memory size", "4,194,304", "KB"
"Cache size", "32,768", "K"
"Number of cores", "8"
"Note", "4,000,000 KB is less than 4 GB"
```

These groups are `key`, `value` and (optional) `suffix`.

Additional requirements:

- The value (i.e., the part after '=') is not necessarily a number
- Any spaces on either side of ':' should be removed in one pass, without backtracking
- The "KB" and "K" string matching is not case sensitive
- The captured groups should always have the same index (ideally, 3 groups for key/value/suffix, with the same group index for all matches)

Clearly, a simple expression like

- `([^=]+) *: *([^=]+)`

does not fully cover the specification above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex that fully covers the spec above is:

```
^([^=]+?) *= *(.+?) *$
```

**EDIT**

Turns out I missed the K/KB part. Here is the amended version:

```
^([^=]+?) *= *(.+?) *(KB?)? *$
```

Comment: This matches all strings but does not produce a separate group for "KB" or "K". +1 for the help.

Comment: @PNS Oops... I've amended the response. Now it should work as requested

Comment: It does work and actually it captures the answers in just 3 groups, always with the same index. Nice! :-)

Comment: As for case insensitiveness, you could also write: `^([^=]+?) *= *(.+?) *([Kk][Bb]?)? *$`

Comment: To make pattern case insensitive you can use compile method with `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag like `Pattern.compile("regex",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);` or just start regex with `(?i)` like `(?i)^([^=]+?) *= *(.+?) *(KB?)? *$`.

Comment: Thanks for that. It may be a bit faster to do it explicitly in this case. It should also be noted that, to remove all white spaces (not just the SPACE character), \s should be used.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
^(.*?)\s*=\s*(?:([\d,]+)\s*(K|KB)$|(.*))
```

`^` - match beginning of line

`(.*?)` capture the left term by matching anything (`?` makes it non-greedy; otherwise it would eat up all the whitespace).

`\s*=\s*` match and discard the equals sign and any space around it.

`(?:([\d,]+)\s*(K|KB)$|(.*))` This long group matches either one thing or the other. `(?:` makes it a non-capturing group, because you don't want to capture the entire thing.

`([\d,]+)\s*(K|KB)$`  if there is a number followed by just K or KB and the end of the string, match that in two groups.

`(.*)` otherwise, match everything that remains in one group.

Comment: This works, but it does not capture the "value" in the same group index all the time. It produces 4 groups instead of 3 and the answer for strings 3 and 4 is in group 4 instead of group 2.

Answer (score 0):

try it and tell me if it worked:

```
(.*) *= *(.*) (.*)
```

Comment: It doesn't, but +1 for the help.

Comment: This does not come close. `(.*)` will always eat up all the whitespace, so your ` *` will never match anything.  After the equals sign you are matching a single character with one group, then everything else with the second group.

Comment: The edited version is better, but it still doesn't work (e.g., it captures the "GB" in the 4th string as a separate answer. You can test it at http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html and verify that.